NFS won't mount automatically, creates rpc symlink on manual mount
My NFS share will not mount automatically. At boot time, it is not mounted and I can't find any logs indicating why. Explicitly running sudo mount -a exits without either mounting the share or returning an error.
The share will mount manually, but reports creating a new systemd link:
$ sudo mount /mnt/share
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/remote-fs.target.wants/rpc-statd.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/rpc-statd.service.

This happens after every reboot -- I have to manually mount the NFS share, and it results in the same output every time.
I've been using the NFS share for months from one machine with Jammy via WSL, and one with Debian stable. This is on a new new machine with Noble, from a fresh install of ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso with nfs-common just installed. The /etc/fstab line is identical to the working machines:
192.168.1.100:/share   /mnt/share   nfs   defaults,rw,sync,mountvers=4,noauto   0   2

How do I fix the underlying issue preventing an automatic mount from happening?
